# Unable to connect to Google Cloud SQL from local AppEnginer server

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jdbc, gcloud

I'm trying to connect to Google Cloud SQL database from a servlet hosted in local AppEngine Server. I'm able to connect using MySQL client but not with JDBC. I'm getting the below error messages. Could you help ?

**Note that when I'm deploying it to App Engine Cloud server, it works but not when deployed to local App Engine.**

```
INFO: Obtaining ephemeral certificate for Cloud SQL instance [test-project-171816:us-central1:test-instance].
java.sql.SQLException: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: com/google/appengine/repackaged/com/google/common/base/Platform
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:957)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:896)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:885)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:860)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:877)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:873)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:422)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:400)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:327)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:270)
    at gcloudsql.HelloAppEngine.doGet(HelloAppEngine.java:85)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
    at com.google.appengine.api.socket.dev.DevSocketFilter.doFilter(DevSocketFilter.java:74)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ResponseRewriterFilter.doFilter(ResponseRewriterFilter.java:134)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.HeaderVerificationFilter.doFilter(HeaderVerificationFilter.java:34)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.ServeBlobFilter.doFilter(ServeBlobFilter.java:63)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:48)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.StaticFileFilter.doFilter(StaticFileFilter.java:122)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doDirectRequest(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:366)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doDirectModuleRequest(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:349)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doFilter(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:116)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppEngineWebAppContext.handle(DevAppEngineWebAppContext.java:95)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService$ApiProxyHandler.handle(JettyContainerService.java:508)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:923)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:547)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:212)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
    at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:409)
    at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: com/google/appengine/repackaged/com/google/common/base/Platform
    at com.google.appengine.repackaged.com.google.common.base.Ticker$1.read(Ticker.java:69)
    at com.google.appengine.repackaged.com.google.common.base.Stopwatch.elapsedNanos(Stopwatch.java:181)
    at com.google.appengine.repackaged.com.google.common.base.Stopwatch.elapsed(Stopwatch.java:194)
    at com.google.appengine.repackaged.com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LoadingValueReference.elapsedNanos(LocalCache.java:3665)
    at com.google.appengine.repackaged.com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.getAndRecordStats(LocalCache.java:2381)
    at com.google.appengine.repackaged.com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.loadSync(LocalCache.java:2336)
    at com.google.appengine.repackaged.com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.lockedGetOrLoad(LocalCache.java:2294)
    at com.google.appengine.repackaged.com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2207)
    at com.google.appengine.repackaged.com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.get(LocalCache.java:4062)
    at com.google.appengine.repackaged.com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.getOrLoad(LocalCache.java:4066)
    at com.google.appengine.repackaged.com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalLoadingCache.get(LocalCache.java:4995)
    at com.google.appengine.repackaged.com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalLoadingCache.getUnchecked(LocalCache.java:5001)
    at com.google.appengine.api.appidentity.AppIdentityServiceImpl.getAccessToken(AppIdentityServiceImpl.java:272)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.extensions.appengine.auth.oauth2.AppIdentityCredential.intercept(AppIdentityCredential.java:98)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.extensions.appengine.auth.oauth2.AppIdentityCredential$AppEngineCredentialWrapper.intercept(AppIdentityCredential.java:243)
    at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:859)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:419)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:352)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:469)
    at com.google.cloud.sql.mysql.SslSocketFactory.obtainInstanceMetadata(SslSocketFactory.java:370)
    at com.google.cloud.sql.mysql.SslSocketFactory.fetchInstanceSslInfo(SslSocketFactory.java:282)
    at com.google.cloud.sql.mysql.SslSocketFactory.getInstanceSslInfo(SslSocketFactory.java:262)
    at com.google.cloud.sql.mysql.SslSocketFactory.createAndConfigureSocket(SslSocketFactory.java:181)
    at com.google.cloud.sql.mysql.SslSocketFactory.create(SslSocketFactory.java:150)
    at com.google.cloud.sql.mysql.SocketFactory.connect(SocketFactory.java:47)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:298)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2253)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2286)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2085)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:795)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:44)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.runtime.Runtime.newInstance_(Runtime.java:140)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.runtime.Runtime.newInstance(Runtime.java:148)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:404)
    ... 42 more


<appengine-web-app xmlns="http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0">
    <threadsafe>true</threadsafe>
    <system-properties>
        <property name="java.util.logging.config.file" value="WEB-INF/logging.properties" />
        <property name="ae-cloudsql.cloudsql-database-url"
            value="jdbc:google:mysql://${INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME}/${database}?user=${user}&amp;password=${password}&amp;useSSL=false" />
        <property name="ae-cloudsql.local-database-url"
            value="jdbc:mysql://google/${database}?cloudSqlInstance=${INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME}&amp;socketFactory=com.google.cloud.sql.mysql.SocketFactory&amp;user=${user}&amp;password=${password}&amp;useSSL=false" />
    </system-properties>
    <use-google-connector-j>true</use-google-connector-j>
</appengine-web-app>
```

Comment: There seems to be a mismatch between the drivers used by the MySql client and your Java code. Could you verify the versions are the same? You should look for: mysql-connector-java in your java code to confirm the version for it. From the error, what it seems is, the java code you wrote is trying to access a method in the driver jar, which is no longer publically accessible.

Comment: Could you share your appengine-web.xml

Comment: @SimoneTallevi-Diotallevi - added below the stack trace.

Comment: It doesn't look like a version mismatch issue. I have mysql-connector-java 5.1.38 which is the same as the dependency version of mysql-socket-factory 1.0.3 but still get the same error.

Comment: The official App Engine documentation has a guide on [using Cloud SQL](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/cloud-sql/) using JDBC which I have tested to work on the local server. You should be able to adapt its configuration for your use. The guide is also available on its [Github page](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/java-docs-samples/tree/master/appengine-java8/cloudsql).